# getSupportFragmentManager doesn't compile on DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

How can I show this :

```
public class TagsDialog extends DialogFragment
{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.tags_dialog, null));
        builder.setMessage("This is a message").setTitle("TAGS");
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

From inside my `Fragment` inside a `ViewPager` :

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment
    {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

    ...

            ImageView btnTags = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.btnTags);
            btnTags.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {

                    DialogFragment dlg = new TagsDialog();
                    //this line doesn't compile
                    dlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tags");

                }
            });
}
}
```

I have tried for ages to get this to work, but `getSupportFragmentManager` is never resolved... any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I feel this is all caused by the support FragmentManager vs the android.app.FragmentManager, however I do not know how to solve this, as I am using the ViewPager from the support library...

getSupportFragmentManager/and all related getFragManager methods like parent and child one always returns the Manager from the support lib, wheras the show method wants the core one.

Imports are:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(); // returns from support lib
DialogFragment dlg = new TagsDialog();
dlg.show(fm, "tags"); // wants core...
```

If I just use core, then `getSupportFragmentManager()` does not exist on `getActivity()`...

Comment: What do you mean by not resolved ? Do you have any stack trace ?

Comment: @Snicolas it does not compile. You know red sqiggly line.

Comment: lol. Where ? Which line, highlight //the culprit line

Comment: The one with `getSupportFragmentManager` on as I mentioned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should double check your imports. You can't use a mix of Fragment & FragmentManager from the support library and from android core apis.

If you use support, use everything from support (from package `android.support.v4.app`). If not, use everything from core api package (`android.app`).

Comment: So use Fragments & FragmentManager from the support library as well.

Comment: Problem solved. The mismatch was solved by making my DialogFragment also come from the support lib.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I do in my Fragment that is in a ViewPager.  The code to show a DialogFragment is the same where ever you would do it though.

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
ConfirmDeleteDialog dialog = new ConfirmDeleteDialog();
dialog.setTargetFragment(RecipeFragment.this, REQUEST_CONFIRM_RC);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString(ConfirmDeleteDialog.EXTRA_CONFIRM_DIALOG_TYPE,
        ConfirmDeleteDialog.CONFIRM_DIALOG_TYPE.COMMIT.name());  // enum determines what to display
dialog.setArguments(b);
dialog.show(fm, "confirm delete");
```

EDIT.

I think you may be missing the **getActivity().**getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: no getFragmentManager return the one from the activity. See the javadoc.

Comment: Then you need to make sure that both your Fragment and DialogFragment classes are from the v4 support library.  (and FragmentManager)

Comment: You may be right (that he has imported the wrong classes), but the support versions need the getActivity() too when done from a support Fragment.

Comment: Really, the docs doesn't say so : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager()

Comment: There was a reason for not using that method, but I can't for the life of me remember why.